# WebKit => [webView mainFrameDocument] == nil (sometimes)

Tags: cocoa, webkit

I tried this method after the page has been loading. But sometimes the webView's mainFrameDocument is empty (nil). It doesn't depend on the URL at all!
[webView mainFrameURL] isn't nil at all time.

en.wikipedia.org      => no problems

heise.de                 => 80 % of time (not pages!) mainFrameDocument == nil
...

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {

    if (frame == [self mainFrame]) {

        if ([self mainFrameDocument] == nil) NSLog(@"mainFrameDocument with URL = %@ is nil!", [self mainFrameURL]);
    }
}
```

2011-06-16 00:31:28.763 WebAppforMac[32025:707] mainFrameDocument with URL = http://www.heise.de/ is nil!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a race condition.

http://en.wikipedia.org/ and http://heise.de/ both send back 301 redirects, but they do it slightly differently. Wikipedia's response has an empty body, while heise.de sends back a short HTML document with the 301. This is just a guess, but what might be happening is that the WebView loads the first document, then calls the listener method, then (in another thread) tries to load the page that's being redirected to. So if the redirect isn't completed fast enough, you'd sometimes get a null main frame.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks !!!

So I got the point: I have to use:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {

    if (frame == [self mainFrame]) {

        if ([**frame document**] == nil) NSLog(@"mainFrameDocument with URL = %@ is nil!", [self mainFrameURL]);
    }
}
```